# Actualizaciones en la app

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo el siguiente caso:

- Tengo una app ya publicada en Play Store. Hasta aquí todo bien.
- Cuando subo actualizaciones de la funcionalidad el diseño de las pantallas, los usuarios descargan la actualización y no refleja los cambios. Solamente cuando desinstalan e instalan nuevamente la app. La app está desarrollada en flutter.

Revisé y todo parece estar bien.

No sé si alguien le ha pasado